# How to clone and application with all its files in the same device?

Tags: backup, apk

Basically what I want is to have the same app twice, but if I use APK Cloner the new app doesn't have the original's app saved data, so what I want is to clone the data of the original APK to the cloned APK too.

Comment: Apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) can do it , but see if you are comfortable with all those permissions it wants

Comment: Be sure to copy files at /sdcard/Android/data/[package.name.of.app] to the path that the cloning app stores its files if you want to clone it's data too, for example an app called Parrallel Space stores the files at /sdcard/Parrallel Space/Android/data/